# How do I change smart contract state with web3.js?

Tags: solidity, web3js, contract-development, state-variable, function

I am using web3.js to interact with a smart contract. I can read values, but I can't change the state with setting functions in the contract.

```
contract MyContract {

    uint number;

    function getNumber() public view returns (uint) {
        return number;
    }

    function changeNumber(uint newNumber) public {
        number = newNumber;
    }

}
```

---

```
const Web3 = require('web3');
const MyContract = require('./build/contracts/MyContract.json');

const init = async () => {
    const web3 = new Web3('http://localhost:9545');
    const id = await web3.eth.net.getId();
    const deployedNetwork = MyContract.networks[id];
    const contract = new web3.eth.Contract(
        MyContract.abi,
        deployedNetwork.address
    );

// initialized to 0 from contract
const getNumber = async() => {
    const number = await contract.methods.getNumber().call();
    console.log(number);
    return number;  
}

const changeNumber = async (newNumber) => {
    await contract.methods.changeNumber(newNumber).call(); 
}

const checkIfNumberIsDifferent = async () => {
    const number2 = await changeNumber(12345).then(()=>{
        console.log(number2)
        return number2;
       })
     await getNumber();
 }

await checkIfNumberIsDifferent();

}
```

But I can never change Number to anything other than 0 (what it is initialized at). How can I do this?

Comment: You are using `.call()` when calling `changeNumber` you should use `.send()` instead. It should look like this: `await contract.methods.changeNumber(newNumber).send(from: "0x12341234...")`, replacing `"0x12341234..."` with your account..

Answer (score 0):

Reading your function `changeNumber()`, you're not actually modifying the smart contract state here. The keyword 'call' is used to query some data from a smart contract method. You may rather sign and send that signed transaction using `signTransaction` from the web3 doc instead. This will cost you gas, so make sure that you have some ETH on your wallet before sending the transaction.

Comment: Thank you François for your helpful response! I am on ganache and truffle, so would I declare a const signPromise = web3.eth.accounts.signTransaction(tx, privateKey);, and then change call to send()?

Comment: I just tried this method for the first time and it looks like it's working well.
You will need to add you wallet using the private key before sending any transaction though. c.f. https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.7.0/web3-eth-accounts.html#wallet-add